# replacing a dot with a character using sed or perl

Tags: sed, perl

I have a file like this

```
KN1234.1
KN2345.1
KN1233.1
```

I want to replace the . with v so that I can get output as

```
KN1234v1
KN2345v1
KN1233v1
```

After the . it is always 1 but after KN I can also have upto 5 digits. Something like this is also possible `KN14345.1` and it's output should be `KN14345v1`

I tried sed command

```
sed 's/KN\d+.1/KN\d+v1/g' file.txt
```

but nothing happened.
How can i fix this?

Perl solution would also be appreciated.

Thanks

Comment: Hi,
I was thinking something else. This would do 
sed 's/\./v/g file.txt'

Thanks for pointing out

Comment: I will look for tr command manual. Thanks for pointing it out.

Comment: `sed 's/\./v/' file.txt`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This:

```
sed 's/KN\d+.1/KN\d+v1/g' file.txt
```

doesn't do anything because your sed is not likely to support `\d` (I think it's from Perl), so the pattern doesn't match anything. 
You may want to refer to this: [Why does my regular expression work in X but not in Y?](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/119905/why-does-my-regular-expression-work-in-x-but-not-in-y)

It wouldn't work as you want regardless, since the `\d` just escapes the `d` in the replacement part, and `+` isn't special, so your numbers get replaced.

In Perl, you might want something like this:

```
perl -pe 's/(KN\d+)\.1/$1v1/'  file.txt
```

Where `$1` expands to the first group in parenthesis, and the dot is escaped, since it's regex for *any character*. Or

```
perl -pe 's/KN\d+\K\.1/v1/'  file.txt
```

Where `\K` kills the preceding part of the match, so that it isn't replaced.

Though if you don't care about the context of the dot, use `tr`. (or `tr///` in Perl).